# Animating SVG icon on hover

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I'm attempting to animate an SVG line icon ONLY on hover. I'd like it to be static when not hovered. I've worked out how to animate the drawing effect, and I can get it kind of working on hover.. however when it's going between the 'from' and 'to' keyframes, the dashes get smaller and it doesn't create the smooth drawing effect I was hoping for. I am doing this purely HTML/CSS.

```css
.bell_line:hover {
  animation: draw 3s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes draw {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset:92;
    stroke-dasharray: 92;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
    stroke-dasharray: 0; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="bell_line" style="margin-left: 100px;margin-top: 100px;">
  <svg class="bell_line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 60.85 38.83">
 <g data-name="bell_line" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10">
   <path class="bell_line" d="M18.43 28.41l5.38-14.11v-3a5.62 5.62 0 0111.23 0v3l5.33 14.11zM29.38 5.67V.5M29.38 33.2v5.13"/>
 </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Would `transition` solve your issue? I usually find it a simpler solution for hover states.

Your css would end up looking like this,

```
.bell_line {    
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 2s ease;
}

.bell_line:hover {
  stroke-dashoffset: 92;
}
```

OR if you want to animate two states (in your case draw off draw on) you will need to create an animation that draws off the dashoffet by its halfway point, then redraws it by it's completion.

Like so,

```
@keyframes draw {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 90;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 180;
  }
} 

.bell_line {    
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 90;
}

.bell_line:hover {
  animation: draw 2s linear forwards;
}
```

Here we only animate the dashoffset to produce the animation effect then reset the

Here's a working example,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bell-line

https://react-bell-line.stackblitz.io

Also just be mindful that the hover state is on the path. You could always make the hover state on the svg then point to the path.

`svg:hover > .bell_line`

This would just mean you can create a larger area to target with the mouse.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment. The animation is more in line with what I'm after, but I was hoping to completely redraw the icon in the hoverstate instead of disappearing. So the icon is there in full, and once you hover, it disappears quickly and then re-draws itself again.

Comment: @Ash I've updated the answer with an animation example for ya :)